# DOMDocument Parse html

Tags: php, xpath, html-parsing, domdocument

I have one html page where there are number of `<tr><td>` elements like

```
<tr>
<td class="notextElementLabel width100">address:</td>
<td style="width: 100%" colspan="1" class="formFieldelement"><b>12284,CA</b></td>
</tr>
```

let say the above `<tr>` is at 4th position means before this elements there are 3 more `<tr>`

Now I want to get the value of address 
so I am doing

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($this->siteHtmlData);
    $tdElements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("td");
    $i=0;
    foreach ($tdElements as $node) {
        if(trim($node->nodeValue) == 'address:'){
            echo "\n\ngot it\n\n";
        }else{
            echo "\n\n---no ---\n\n";
        }

    }
```

How can I get the value of "12284,CA". Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: If you have access to the HTML, you should give your target an id, using which you could identify it easily.

Comment: @Truth : see it's client page so don't tell me to use id if it is not there, check the below answer, we are here to give right solution, not to give useless advice.

Comment: @DineshGoyal: We are here to spread knowledge. We are *not* here to offend people who give us perfectly sensible advice, and we are *not* here to demand that others solve our own problems for free.

Comment: @Jon I do agree with you, but by asking question, we are increasing knowledge as well as show more options to coming visitor.

Comment: @DineshGoyal: No. That's only true if your question is applicable generally, among other things. "How can I get the value so I can tell my boss I did the job" is not such a question.

Comment: @dinesh first of all, I said if you have access. Second,I'm trying to help you, so be respectful for the person giving of his time to help you!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the logic behind your query is simple enough that it can be expressed entirely in XPath syntax:

```
//td[text()="address:"]/following-sibling::td/b/text()
```

This finds any `<td>` node that has a text equal to `"address:"`, grabs the following `<td>`, goes into the `<b>` inside it and gets you the text it finds there.

That means you can do

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//td[text()="address:"]/following-sibling::td/b)');
```

It will immediately output the result you are looking for.

Comment: can you please write the full code, any why there is comment before your code //td[text()

Comment: @DineshGoyal: That's because the SO syntax highlighter thinks it's a comment. In reality it's just XPath syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the `<tr>` elements, then parse its children, similar to:

```
$trElements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("tr");
foreach ($trElements as $node) {
    $children = $node->childNodes;
    foreach( $children as $child)
        echo $child->textContent; // or $child->nodeValue
}
```

This outputs: `address: 12284,CA`

Now, if there are more `<tr>` elements that are not the address, you will need to parse the `$children` list of nodes to make sure you find `"address:"`, and then once you do, you know the value of next child is the value you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by myself which is similar to nickb's answer

```
$tdElements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("td");
    $tdCnt  = $tdElements->length;

    for ($idx = 0; $idx < $tdCnt; $idx++) {

        if(trim($tdElements->item($idx)->nodeValue) == 'address:'){
            echo $tdElements->item($idx+1)->nodeValue;
        }
    }
```

Hope it will helps