# PHP: How to find <div and /div in a string?

Tags: php, html, strpos

I pass an array of html code to a php function with the intention of extracting and returning a subset of it.

Here's a partial example of the data passed in:

```
[0] => <div class="positionIs" style="float:right;width:181px;">
[1] => <table class="datab" style="width:100%;">
[2] => <tr>
[3] => <th colspan="2" style="padding:4px;">Position ist...
[4] => </th>
[5] => </tr>
[6] => <tr class="hell">  
[7] => <td style="text-align:left;">...tats&auml;chliche Position
[8] => </td>
[9] => <td style="font-weight:bold;padding:2px;">
[10] => <div style="text-align: center;border:1px solid black;padding:1px;height:1.4em;width:1.4em;background-color:#ffffff;">
[11] => </div>
```

To return, e.g. the first table row ([2] - [5]) it seems to me that I need to test for "

I've tried to do it with strpos, but it just doesn't work as I expect it to.  That's probably because of the presence of the "<" and "/" in the strings.  I've tried escaping it with a backslash but that didn't work either.  How should I test these strings?

As requested below, here's the code from my function:

```
$str_out = '';
$tracker = 0;
$start = '<tr';
$end = '/tr';
for ($i = 0, $ii = count($arr_in); $i < $ii; $i++)
{
    $str_out .= $arr_in[$i];
    if (strpos($arr_in[$i], $start) === true)
    {
        $tracker++;
    }
    if (strpos($arr_in[$i], $end) === true)
    {
        $tracker--;
    }
    if (!$tracker) break;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you used to try it yourself?

Comment: Take a look at PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class. Attempting to process an irregular language like HTML with any sort of regex (and I include `strpos` in that) is the way of madness.

Comment: @WesleyE - updated as per your request.

Comment: @Mike W - I'm not acquanted with PHP's DOMDocument class.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @midnig: You want to use `DOMDocument` and also most likely `DOMXPath`, which allows you to use [XPath 1.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) syntax to "query" an XML/HTML structure. Search the site and Google them.

Comment: @midnig: For a quick example of what is possible see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138158/domdocument-parse-html/11138390#11138390).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos` won't return `TRUE`. It will return the position the first character of the 'needle' is found or return `FALSE` if it has not been found. For more info check the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

So instead of using

`if (strpos($arr_in[$i], $start) === true)`

you can check for non-false like this:

`if (strpos($arr_in[$i], $start) !== false)`

Comment: Thank you!  I recall now that in other cases I tested for !== false and this is the reason why.